# Interval Timer in XPages losing Date value on refresh

Tags: xpages

Hi I have a 'mail in' application and display the emails waiting in the queue (line) on a 'wallboard'. I wish to refresh the display every x seconds using a partial refresh of the repeat containing the mail data. This works fine other than the I have a problem with a date field, which displays correctly until the first refresh, when it converts to the default 1 Jan 1970. I use the created date to calculate the no. of minutes the mail has been waiting - not shown here.
Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

On the XPage I have:

```
<xp:scriptBlock
id="scriptBlockRefresh">
<xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[
            setInterval(function() {
                XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:mailInPanel}", {})
            }, 5 * 1000)
        ]]>
</xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>

<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:miniWallboardBean.loadOutstandingMailin();}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>

<xp:panel id="mailInPanel">
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" value="#{miniWallboardBean.outstandingMailin}" var="rowData">
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{rowData.from}"></xp:text>
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2" value="#{rowData.subject}"></xp:text>
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField5" value="#{javascript:rowData.getCreatedDate().toJavaDate()}"></xp:text>           
</xp:repeat>
</xp:panel>
```

In my Mailin Class

```
import lotus.domino.DateTime;

public class Mailin {
private String from;
private String subject;
private DateTime createdDate;
private String owner;


public String getFrom()         {return from;}
public void setFrom(String from)        {this.from = from;}
public String getSubject()          {return subject;}
public void setSubject(String subject)  {this.subject = subject;}
public DateTime getCreatedDate()        {return createdDate;}
public void setCreatedDate(DateTime createdDate) {this.createdDate = createdDate;}
public String getOwner()            {return owner;}
public void setOwner(String owner)      {this.owner = owner;}
}
```

I get the data from view columns in my business logic:

```
public List <Mailin> getOutstandingMailin(){    
    ArrayList<Mailin> outstandingMailin = new ArrayList<Mailin>();
    try {
        ViewEntryCollection entries = NCLWallboardUtil.getAllEntries("Server","DB","View"); //Method to get a collection

        if (entries !=null) {
            ViewEntry entry = entries.getFirstEntry();
            while (entry !=null){
            Mailin mailin = loadMailInFromEntry(entry);
            outstandingMailin.add(mailin);
            ViewEntry oldEntry = entry;
            entry = entries.getNextEntry(entry);
            oldEntry.recycle();
        }
            entries.recycle();
        }
            } catch (NotesException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    return outstandingMailin;
}


private Mailin loadMailInFromEntry(ViewEntry entry) throws NotesException{
Mailin mailin = new Mailin();
mailin.setFrom((String) entry.getColumnValues().get(0));
mailin.setSubject((String) entry.getColumnValues().get(3));
mailin.setOwner((String) entry.getColumnValues().get(5));
mailin.setCreatedDate((DateTime) entry.getColumnValues().get(4));
return mailin;
```

}

In my session scope bean I have:

```
   public class MiniWallboardBean implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List <Mailin> outstandingMailin;
private MiniWallboard miniWB;   

public MiniWallboardBean(){
miniWB = new MiniWallboard();}

public void loadOutstandingMailin(){
    try{
    setOutstandingMailin(miniWB.getOutstandingMailin());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


public void setOutstandingMailin(List <Mailin> outstandingMailil{
 this.outstandingMailin = outstandingMailin;}
public List <Mailin> getOutstandingMailin() {
  return outstandingMailin;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateTimes, like other Domino objects, are not serializable. So once the initially page load is completed and the Session recycled, your DateTime will also be recycled.

Store the values as Java Dates instead and you will be fine.